# How to fix chromium build-errors on ubuntu 32bit?

Tags: build, ubuntu-10.04, chromium

I downloaded chromium source tarball and started building on Ubuntu 32 bit OS as below.

1. extracted source tarball
2. installed depot_tools and exported its PATH
3. In shell executed below commands

   $ cd [CHROMIUM_ROOT]/chromium/src
   $ sudo ./build/install-build-deps.sh
   $ sudo ./build/gyp_chromium
   $ make chrome

I got the below errors for last used **make** command

**../native_client/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/x86_64-nacl/bin/gcc -c src/untrusted/stubs/crti_x86_32.S -o /home/yugandroid/Desktop/chromium/src/out/Debug/obj/gen/tc_newlib/lib32/crti.o -std=gnu99 -m32 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -mtls-use-call -DNACL_BUILD_ARCH=x86 -D_*linux*_ -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS=1 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_BSD_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_PREFIX=NACL_ -DNACL_BUILD_SUBARCH=32 -I/home/yugandroid/Desktop/chromium/src/out/Debug/obj/gen/tc_newlib/include -I.. -I../ppapi -I.. -I../ppapi
FAILED: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

**make: *** [out/Debug/obj/gen/tc_newlib/lib32/crti.o] Error 255**

I found similar error posted at [Linux Build Instructions for chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions)

Somebody replied for above problem as **This can be resolved by adding the glibc.i686 library and other missing libs (as root): yum install glibc.i686 libstdc++.so.6 libz.so.1**

I tried **$ sudo yum install glibc.i686 libstdc++.so.6 libz.so.1**

**output**

[sudo] password for yugandroid:

Setting up Install Process

No package glibc.i686 available.

No package libstdc++.so.6 available.

No package libz.so.1 available.

Nothing to do

If anybody know the solution please help me regarding this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you sync your repository with the most recent state of the repository? Extracting the tarball gets you part of the way there, but you'll need to run `gclient` to pull down all the various dependencies associated with the project. It'll take a little while.

See http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code for details, but as a quick overview: you'll need to configure your client by executing `gclient config https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src`, and then sync to the most recent version using `gclient sync`.

Run both of those from the root of your repository (not the `src` directory: the directory that *contains* `src`). I think that should get you on track.

Comment: I did gclient sync so, now i am not getting above errors but i got new error. please check my new question [memory allocation error in chromium build on ubuntu 32bit OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683997/memory-allocation-error-in-chromium-build-on-ubuntu-32bit-os)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30913546/285594 - can you please fix this answer? it never worked here was all step by step mentioned.