# Google Chrome - How to compile Google Chrome in Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-c++, windows-8.1, ninja

Documentation mentioned to compile i have to follow this instruction for Windows: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows

So i did all the steps, but the following is failing how can i resolve it?

[image]

```
C:\tpt\depot_tools>mkdir out\Debug

C:\tpt\depot_tools>ninja -C out\Debug chrome
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet
vinden.

ninja: Entering directory `out\Debug'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DONE. Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. Visual Studio 2013 Community edition

Install git https://git-scm.com/download/win

Step 1:

```
C:\>mkdir folder
C:\>cd folder
C:\>unzip https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/tools/depot_tools.zip
C:\folder>dir
 Directory of C:\folder
18/04/2015  02:59    <DIR>          depot_tools
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  67 387 064 320 bytes free
```

Step 2:

```
C:\folder\depot_tools>git config --global user.name "John Doe"
C:\folder\depot_tools>git config --global user.email "jdoe@email.com"
C:\folder\depot_tools>git config --global core.autocrlf false
C:\folder\depot_tools>git config --global core.filemode false
C:\folder\depot_tools>git config --global color.ui true
```

Step 3:

```
/*
NOTE: A) Add those in the environment variable

C:\Users\folder>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\Sy
stem32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\S
kype\Phone\;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program File
s (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\folder\depot_tools

NOTE: B) Add those in the environment variable

C:\folder>set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
C:\folder>echo %DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN%
0
*/


C:\>cd folder
C:\folder>fetch chromium
// or use fetch --no-history chromium 
//.....(wait: 1 hour or 3 hour just wait??? and shut up)
C:\folder\chromium>gclient sync
C:\folder\chromium>gclient runhooks
```

Step 4:

```
C:\folder\chromium\src>ninja -C out\Debug chrome && out\Debug\chrome.exe 
// NOTE: this takes several hours
```

SUCCESS:

[image]

**OPTIONAL NOTE:**

- you need to have enough disk space. otherwise the compile/build fails

[image]

- you need to have enough memory space. otherwise it also fail

[image]

- where to get started with code?

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for putting this together.

Comment: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up

Comment: git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git