# Chromium Build Failed on Windows:D3D Compiler DLL (\third_party\angle\src)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg, chromium

I have followed same step mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902179/google-chrome-how-to-compile-google-chrome-in-windows). Few extra flag I have set get propriety FFMPEG codec. Its failing every time, with following logs.

```
[233/19712] ACTION Copying D3D Compiler DLL...
FAILED: F:\Chrome\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe gyp-win-tool action-wrapper environment.x86 copy_compiler_dll_target_copy_dll_a30e198148542d4bce19a5c818c6884f..rsp ..\..\third_party\angle\src
[233/19712] CC obj\third_party\icu\source\stubdata\icuuc.stubdata.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

For FFMPEG using following set command:

```
set GYP_DEFINES=branding=Chromium buildtype=Official component=shared_library disable_nacl=1 enable_automation=0 enable_captive_portal_detection=0 enable_google_now=0 enable_hidpi=0 fastbuild=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome incremental_chrome_dll=0 proprietary_codecs=1 remoting=0
```

**My System Information Details:**

> Windows 10 64 Bit 8 GB RAM. Trail Version of Visual Studio 2015
>   Installed, but now it is expired. Now I have installed Community
>   Version 2013 update 4.

Does it effect both version effect the execution? Checked in path, its using `Window Kit 8.1`. What other part should I check for successful execution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Win10 SDK. That did it for me.
http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13945#p29872

LE: However, later on in the build you may find all sorts of not found headers and/or other compile errors. This is most likely due to installing Win 10 SDK **after** having first fired the `build\gyp_chromium.py` command and realizing that it had not worked. What you need to do in order to move on is delete all the precompiled headers generated in your target output (eg. `out\Debug`) and then rerun the `build\gyp_chromium.py` and `ninja -C ...` commands.

I have picked this up from Daniel Bratell's answer at https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/PacUmAmrWrk

LLE: If still having issues delete the `out` folder altogether and rerun `gclient runhooks`; then the `ninja -C out\Debug` command

Comment: Thank you for answering this, but I could not verify this now, as don't have environment now. I had succesfully built chromium using above flags, but it could not helped in playing avi file format. So used webchimerajs, which awesome and provide all VLC player capability inside NW.